# Are questions regarding "telephone networks" on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions regarding telephone networks or SMS networks considered on-topic?

I have two (real) examples:

1. **How do we find out the "sending" date and time of an SMS?**

   When we receive an SMS, the date and time of receipt is shown. This means that if someone sends me an SMS *while* my phone is switched off, the date and time of the SMS receipt will reflect the time *when* I switch on the phone.

   How do we find out the estimated actual date and time when the SMS was sent (the time when the [SMSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_message_service_center) had received the message)? Is it even possible?
2. **How do we tell when an SMS we sent expires?**

   If we send an SMS to a friend, the message [may expire and be deleted in the SMSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_message_service_center#Validity_period_of_an_SMS_message).

   How do we *know* when the message we sent expires and never reach its intended destination?

Are these questions on-topic here? Or are they better suited on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) / [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

"Telephone Networks / Telephony"? Yes.

**Your examples**

But "telephone networks" is not what your example questions are primarily about. Your examples are more about using SMS services from some provider. (As opposed to engineering and providing SMS services.) So "setup/deploy voice-over-IP for my $ob" yes, on-topic.

And my uncertain opinion on your examples specifically: Better asked over on Stack Overflow where there are a bunch 'o [SMS questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sms) already.

Comment: But isn't Stackoverflow mainly for questions related to code / programming itself?

Comment: "my uncertain opinion" suggests that I do not know. I suggest you take the time to search through SO, SU and SF to see where you think these examples fit (if you really are going to ask them, as opposed to having just made them up for demo).